# java socket inputstream shows unreadable data

Tags: java, serversocket, datainputstream

```
String serverName = "192.168.1.18";
int port = 10900;
Socket client = new Socket(serverName, port);
OutputStream outToServer = client.getOutputStream();
DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(outToServer);
String message = "hello";
out.writeUTF(message );
InputStream is = client.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
System.out.println(br.readLine());
```

it show following output:
    Connecting to 192.168.1.18 on port 10900
    Just connected to /192.168.1.18:10900
    "N���`�\ "

Comment: try `InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is,,"UTF-8");`

Comment: And what is the code on the server side?

Comment: Did you send unreadable data?